# Get the output of python subprocess in console

Tags: python, c, django

```
process = subprocess.check_output(BACKEND+"mainbgw setup " + str(NUM_USERS), shell=True,\
                                          stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

I am using the above statement to run a C program in django-python based server for some computations, there are some `printf()` statements whose output I would like to see on `stdout` while the server is running and executing the subprocess, how can that be done ?

Comment: If after the subprocess has ended is ok, you can use - `print(process)` ? Otherwise you may want to use `Popen` .

Comment: @AnandSKumar could you please provide a small example code

Answer (score 0):

If you actually don't need the output to be available to your python code as a string, you can just use `os.system`, or `subprocess.call` without redirecting `stdout` elsewhere. Then `stdout` of your C program will just go directly to `stdout` of your python program.

If you need both streaming `stdout` and access to the output as a string, you should use `subprocess.Popen` (or the old `popen2.popen4`) to obtain a file descriptor of the output stream, then repeatedly read lines from the stream until you exhausted it. In the mean time, you keep a concatenated version of all data you grabbed. [This](https://amagard.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/running-a-sub-process-from-a-python-script/) is an example of the loop.